# como sumar una columna en r con respecto a dos variables

Tags: r

tengo un dataframe de la siguiente caractaristica

```
SBAN     MES    CAPTACIONES
121     ENERO    $1512
121     ENERO    $156
121     FEBRERO  $186
133     MARZO    $1568
144     ENERO    $1568
151     ENERO    $1513
151     FEBRERO  $1513
```

Requiero sumar las filas de tal manera que me quede un unico valor de SBAN por MES, es decir.

```
121 ENERO  $1668
121 FEBRERO $186
ETC
```

Comment: ¿`CAPTACIONES`  es una columna numérica? ¿o como se ve en el ejemplo es una cadena a la que hay que convertir en numérica?

Comment: Si señor, es una columna numerica, es el valor en millones que depositan los clientes, de igual manera tengo una columna para saldo en cuenta de ahorros y corriente a la que debo aplicar lo mismo, dejando un unico valor de SBAN y MES, lo que requiero es que la base me quede como en excel cuando se realiza una tabla dinamica y se agrupan los datos sumando los valores de x columnas; en este caso respetando la columa SBAN y MES dejando un unico valor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas básicamente agrupar y sumar, puedes hacerlo con R base:

```
aggregate(CAPTACIONES ~ MES + SBAN, df, sum)
```

Es decir, agrupamos por `MES` y `SBAN` y aplicamos `sum` a `CAPTACIONES`

O puedes pasarte directamente al universo de `tidyverse`, donde las cosas son un poco más explicativas y claras:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(MES, SBAN) %>% 
  summarise(CAPTACIONES = sum(CAPTACIONES))
```

Comment: Mil gracias Patricio, me funciona perfectamente Dios te pague.